# Extact images using ItextSharp

Tags: javascript, c#, pdf, itext

I have a question regarding PDF. If I use the code below with a PDF with 5 images on it, it works perfectly fine. The same with a PDF having 10 to 15 images throws an error.

```
var fields=[];

for (var i = 0; i <= this.numFields - 1; i++) {
   fields.push(this.getNthFieldName(i));
}

this.submitForm({
cURL: "http://localhost/W.svc/Imagesonpdf",
aFields: fields,
cSubmitAs: "FDF" // the default, not needed here
});
```

Is there any way we can call the Web Service with Images. If I call the web Service from the Submit button, it works, but not able to get the images on the pdf.

Comment: How does this relate to [tag:itext]?

Comment: i'm getting the file using ItextSharp.

Comment: Which error is thrown? Is it an error thrown by JavaScript or by the backend?

Comment: there is no error, it don't connect with the web service,I can not see any errro in the console, It's just say Genral Error, Nothing done. If I'm removing Images on the pdf two images it started working